# Can I simulate power supply getting offline using udev or in other ways under Linux?

Tags: udev, power-management, events

I have created the rule `/etc/udev/rules.d/80.power.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="0", RUN+="/root/test.sh"
```

Then I execute the command `udevadm trigger  /sys/class/power_supply/ACAD -c offline -v`  (note **offline**) and I see that `/root/test.sh` *is not* executed.

If I set `ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="1"` and execute `udevadm trigger  /sys/class/power_supply/ACAD -c online -v` (note **online**), then `/root/test.sh` *is* executed.

Is there any way to simulate the power unplug event so that udev would execute my script? If there are ways without udev, it's also okay. The point is that I need to simulate power plug/unplug situation on Linux. Thank you for attention!